# Correct usage of "in"

Tags: word-usage

Are these usages of the word 'in' correct(grammatically speaking)?

> 1. "In allowing them to get away unpunished, he tacitly approved of their behavior."
> 2. "In repeated sampling the long-run relative frequencies of the confidence intervals that contain the true value of the parameter will approach the confidence level."

I looked at the various definitions of the "in" at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in) but I didn't find one that seemed to justify this usage. I still find it used in this fashion however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they both are correct. Prepositions are tricky little things!

from the dictionary on my computer:

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)

> ***in***: 8 [ with verbal noun ] as an integral part of (an activity): in planning public expenditure it is better to be prudent.

Comment: What dictionary?  It's better to use an online source if you can find one, that way you can link directly.

Comment: LOL! It's the New Oxford American Dictionary. Just checked Merriam-Websters online--my usual online dictionary, but it merely presents 5 definitions for <in>. And OP's experience with Dictionary.com wasn't useful.

Comment: The regular old Oxford English dictionary is online, and includes the definition you quote:  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in  .  It's always nice to link to the OED, that way the Brits on here can't complain.  :)

Comment: I'm new here. I thought what the OP wanted was an answer. There's the answer. I was hoping to give the English Language Learner a quick response, explaining why the usage is correct. Isn't this an ESL board? Why would Brits complain on an ESL board?

Perhaps I need to lurk around a little before I jump in and try to help people. Perhaps I should just find something better to do with my time.

Comment: You can review some of the other accepted answers to see what a "good" answer looks like.  In general if you say something is correct, it's not a bad idea to have a reference to back you up, where convenient.  Especially for things like simple definitions, it only takes a moment to link to an online dictionary.   Anyway your answer is fine, but if you edit to include the link I'll upvote it.

Comment: Also my comment about the Brits was just a little joke -- one thing I've learned on here is that what I speak is significantly different from "proper" British English.